# Memory fault in my simple program in C

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, command-line

when i run my app like ./a.out i have this error:
I compile my app like: gcc test1.c.
Memory fault

my code is

```
 int main (void)
 {
   DIR *dp;
   struct dirent *ep;
   const char *path_dir ="/home/risorse/ae23054/Giuseppe";//Inserire la directory qui

   dp = opendir (path_dir);
   if (dp != NULL)
     {
       while (ep = readdir (dp)){
         printf(ep->d_name);
         char nome_file[256];
         strcpy(nome_file,ep->d_name);

         FILE *fd=fopen(nome_file, "a+");
         fprintf(fd,"\nEXIT");
         fclose(fd);
       }
       (void) closedir (dp);
     }
   else
     perror ("Non posso aprire la directory");

   return -1;
}
```

thanks

Comment: Did you do any debugging.

Comment: check the return value of `fopen`.

Comment: You didn't initialized `ep` struct ?

Comment: Please don't printf d_name, use `puts(d_name)` or `printf("%s", d_name)`, otherwise you will have problems if d_name contains an escape sequence like "%s". Also don't copy d_name to nome_file without checking any sizes. First according to `man readdir` d_name size can depend on the platform. Second there is no need to strcpy, you can pass d_name directly to fopen.

Answer (score 3):

You use fopen result without checking it is it NULL.

Answer (score 2):

If your current directory isn't `path_dir` and your current working directory doesn't contain files that have the same names as the files at `path_dir`, `fopen` will return NULL.

Your program is most likely crashing because you don't check the return value before attempting to use it (in the following `fprintf` and `fclose` calls.

A possible solution could be to change to the directory before trying to `fopen` the files. This will mean that you get the expected behavior. Although, you still need to check for NULL in case the file is deleted/moved right after you get the directory entry.

```
...
dp = opendir (path_dir);
if (dp != NULL)
  {
    fchdir(dirfd(dp));
...
```